# Xamarin forms press and release recognizer for SKCanvasView

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm new to Xamarin and would like to implement something like animated circular "SOS button" in Xamarin forms. Intended functionality is that if user presses and holds the button for more than 3 second (countdown period) some activity will be initiated.

I want the SOS button to be visually attractive so when user presses and holds the button some progress animation will occur around the button indicating that the button is pressed and countdown to SOS action is started. If the button will be released sooner everything will be reset back to its initial state.

We've created different button bitmaps (animations) that represent the countdown progress and decided to use SKCanvasView to render them during the countdown period. And now the issue begins as we need to recognize Press and Release events made on SKCanvasView from SKiaSharp.Views.Forms assembly. There is only TapGestureRecognizer available according to my investigation.

Can you recommend, point me to solution how to catch press and release events on SKCanvasView in Xamarin forms so I can implement above mentioned functionality?

Thank you

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll need to **show the code you've attempted**. Its much easier to give useful advice with respect to specific code. (And this will help future readers - SO is about creating a *repository of knowledge*). In this case, show code that creates an SKCanvasView, with an attached TapGestureRecognizer - and get that much to work. I understand this isn't your goal - but its as close as you are able to get to that goal, so please get that far and post it.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've used following initial approach. I've placed button on canvas and used its Pressed and Released events to draw on background canvas. I will continue to investigate more regarding custom renderers that might be ideal fine tuned solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             x:Class="SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Basics.TapToggleFillPage"
             Title="Tap Toggle Fill">

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="Canvas" PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        </skia:SKCanvasView>
        <Button Text="SOS"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="160"
                HeightRequest="160" 
                BackgroundColor="#B91F67" 
                BorderColor="Red"
                BorderRadius="120" 
                TextColor="White" 
                FontSize="40" 
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Pressed="OnButtonPressed"
                Released="OnButtonReleased"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```